# Как проверить существует ли поле в документе с оператором И

Tags: elasticsearch

Есть обычный поиск, где мы ищем по `category_id` и существованию характеристики `fields.id`

```
"query" => [
  "bool" => [
    "must" => [
      "match" => [
        "category_id" => $category_id
      ], [
        "exists" => [ 
          "field" => "fields.$id"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Поиск работает, встала задача добавить еще одну проверку на существование характеристики `fields.id`, но чтобы у нее был оператор `И`, то есть нужно получить все товары, где:

Категория `= 1`
Есть характеристика с `id = 1`
ИЛИ есть характеристика с `id =2`

В документации нашел возможность выбора оператора, только для `match`

```
"match" => [
  "message" => [
    "query": "this is a test",
    "operator": "or"
  ]
]
```

Есть ли подобное решение для `exists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам просто нужно использовать "should":
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

```
"query" => [
  "bool" => [
    "must" => [
      "match" => [
        "category_id" => $category_id
      ]
    ],
    "should" => [
      [
        "exists" => [ 
          "field" => "fields.$id1"
        ]
      ],
      [
        "exists" => [ 
          "field" => "fields.$id2"
        ]
      ],
    ]
  ]
]
```